# How to find $\frac{d}{dx}2x^{2x}$ by implicit differentiation?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Use logarithmic differentiation to differentiate the function with respect to $x$:  $$y=(2x)^{2x}$$

I took the natural logarithm of both sides to get 
$$
\ln(y)=2x \ln(2x)
$$ And then the implicit differentiation is 
$$\frac{d}{dy}(\ln(y)) \times \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}2x\ln(2x)$$
That is, 
$$\frac{1}{y} \times \frac{dy}{dx}=2 \times \ln(2x) + 2x \times \frac{1}{x}$$ Multiplying both sides by $y=2x^{2x}$ I get 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=2x^{2x} \times (2\ln(2x)+2)$$
 Factor out the $2$ to get 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=2x^{2x} \times 2(\ln(2x)+1)$$

The [solution](https://cdn.kutasoftware.com/Worksheets/Calc/03%20-%20Logarithmic%20Differentiation.pdf) shows that

[image]

My **question** is in the solution: it's shown as $\ln(x)$ instead of $\ln(2x)$. I understand the derivatives are the same and that constant is just a multiplier for scaling, but I'm a little confused at that point.

Comment: What do you mean by $\ln(x)$ instead of $\ln(2x)$? What is the whole solution exactly shows? Note that $\ln(2x)=\ln 2+\ln x$. Also $2(2x)^{2x}\neq (4x)^{2x}$.

Comment: No worries, just wanted to make sure it was presented correctly so that someone can help.

Comment: Here is a link to the original question number 1 https://cdn.kutasoftware.com/Worksheets/Calc/03%20-%20Logarithmic%20Differentiation.pdf

Comment: I don't think you meant $(2x)^{2x}$. The link you gave shows $2x^{2x}$.

Comment: I think I started out as $\frac{dy}{dx}2x^{2x}$ but lost all my wits when I couldn't enter it correctly typeset.

Answer (score 2):

1) The problem on the worksheet is $2x^{2x}$ and not $(2x)^{2x}.$
This is your fundamental problem.

2) You have a big mistake in your simplification.
 $(2x)^{2x}(2f(x)) \ne (4x)^{2x}f(x)$

3) $\ln(2x) = \ln x + \ln 2$ so sometimes you will not agree with the answer sheet because of this. This is not your problem, but something to be aware of.